# Undefined References to Python DLL Variables

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, linker, 64-bit

I'm trying to embed Python 3.3 in my 64 bit application, but my linker is generating these errors:

```
=== Sandblox, Windows ===
obj\Windows\python\version.o:version.cpp undefined reference to `__imp_PyExc_ValueError'
obj\Windows\xml\xml.o:xml.cpp undefined reference to `__imp_PyUnicode_Type'
obj\Windows\xml\xml.o:xml.cpp undefined reference to `__imp__Py_NoneStruct'
=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 2 seconds) ===
```

Yes, I did link to `python33.lib`.

Ordinarily you'd expect errors like this to be generated when the library isn't being linked properly, but I referenced plenty of Python functions in both files, and none of them got complaints. It seems like the reference errors are only being generated for global variables like types and Py_None.

What can I do to fix this?

The command Code::Blocks generates is:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe 
-LC:\MinGW\lib -LC:\Python33\libs  -o bin\Windows\Sandblox.exe obj\Windows\block.o 
obj\Windows\engine\irrlicht\renderengine.o obj\Windows\main.o obj\Windows\module.o 
obj\Windows\python\version.o obj\Windows\xml\xml.o -lpython33 -lIrrlicht)
```

Comment: This may seem like a stupid question, but: Any chance you have multiple Python installations, and you're using the header files from the wrong one?

Comment: I've made mistakes as stupid as that before, but I'm certain I only have one Python distribution installed on this computer.

Comment: How did you create libpython33.a? It is not part of the standard Python installation. Try libpython from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#libpython

Comment: Oh sorry, it's python33.lib - it WAS part of the of the standard installation in the libs/ folder. I guess I mistyped.

Comment: python33.lib is for msvc compilers. For mingw64, use libpython33.a.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, that fixed it! Can you write a full answer so I can mark it as the solution?